# Searchable finite field

Tags: regular-expressions, search-problem, finite-fields, minimization

Let $F$ be a large finite field, where the elements are strings of length $n$. We require, addition, multiplication, and division to be efficient (polynomial in $n$).

We say that $F$ is **searchable** if for any $u \in F$ and string $x$, we can find efficiently find a string $s \in F$ such that

- $x$ is a substring of $s \cdot u$
- The number of lexicographically earlier strings $s' \in F$ with this property is $\mathcal o(n)$

We say that $F$ is **regex-searchable** if instead of requiring $x$ to be a substring of $s \cdot u$, we require $s \cdot u$ to satisfy the $x$ when interpreted as a regular expression.

For any $n$, can find a searchable field with strings of length $>n$? What about a regex-searchable field?

Comment: Do you want F itself to be efficiently constructible? As I recall, we only even know how to Co structure finite fields efficiently using GRH or using probabilistic algorithms. What kind of assumptions are you okay with?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow $F$ is all strings of length $n$. Also probabilistic algorithms are fine.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is there a bijection between strings and field elements, so the field must have characteristic 2? Or can elements be represented by more than one string?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow it's bijective, but I do not require the strings to be binary strings.

Comment: So you're saying that the field is actually some extension field of the form $GF(q^m)$ and the strings are over $GF(q)$.

Comment: @kodlu the strings are just sequence of symbols. The number of symbols is $k$, for some prime power $k$, so that the field must be isomorphic to $GF(k^n)$.